# Error Domain=NSPOSIXErrorDomain Code=2 "No such file or directory"

Tags: ios, swift, nsurlsession, nsurlsessiondownloadtask, nsurlsessionconfiguration

I am facing weird issue while try to download file using `URLSession` and `URLSessionConfiguration.background(withIdentifier: Bundle.main.bundleIdentifier!)`

While start downloading file using `URLSession.downloadTask` with background configuration.

Downloading not working properly in iOS iOS 12.* versions and working properly on newer versions.

In iOS 12.* versions I found weird issue that after fresh installation from Xcode or AppStore downloading file gives error below.

```
2021-02-16 10:25:44.448330+0530 Brain Wellness App[512:141574] Task <546389FE-6503-4F43-A01C-C174A09C2892>.<45> load failed with error Error Domain=NSPOSIXErrorDomain Code=2 "No such file or directory" UserInfo={NSErrorFailingURLStringKey=***, NSErrorFailingURLKey=***, _NSURLErrorRelatedURLSessionTaskErrorKey=(
"BackgroundDownloadTask <546389FE-6503-4F43-A01C-C174A09C2892>.<45>",
"LocalDownloadTask <546389FE-6503-4F43-A01C-C174A09C2892>.<45>"
), _NSURLErrorFailingURLSessionTaskErrorKey=BackgroundDownloadTask <546389FE-6503-4F43-A01C-C174A09C2892>.<45>} [2]
Error is Error Domain=NSPOSIXErrorDomain Code=2 "No such file or directory" UserInfo={NSErrorFailingURLStringKey=***, NSErrorFailingURLKey=***, _NSURLErrorRelatedURLSessionTaskErrorKey=(
"BackgroundDownloadTask <546389FE-6503-4F43-A01C-C174A09C2892>.<45>",
"LocalDownloadTask <546389FE-6503-4F43-A01C-C174A09C2892>.<45>"
), _NSURLErrorFailingURLSessionTaskErrorKey=BackgroundDownloadTask <546389FE-6503-4F43-A01C-C174A09C2892>.<45>}
```

But after closing and relaunching app from Home screen file downloading works normally as it should be.

Also background download functionality was working normally around 1 month ago in iOS 12.* versions. I am getting above error in iOS 12.* versions from few days only earlier it was working fine.

Is anyone face this issue earlier and found solutions for this issue ?

If yes then please help me solve this issue.

Answer (score 0):

This error may be caused by a download task running in the background. Too many NSURLSessionDownloadTasks have been created in one go.
Before starting the download, cancel the URLSession and then start the task.